# ` - как вставить «обратную кавычку» в коде между обратными кавычками?

Tags: поддержка

В ответах - не проблема, а при обмене кодом в комментариях, если в нем встречается символ **`** — будет провал)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тест кавычки `\``

Comment: Видимо, как обычно, экранируя ее обратным слешем ^

Comment: `\`` упс (V) ( ;...; ) (V)

Comment: Еще работает 2+ кавычки: \`\`foo\`bar\`\` = ``foo`bar``. Но только если экранируемая кавычка не первый и не последний символ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
`it`s good`
```

> `it`s good`

```
``it`s good``
```

> `` it`s good ``

````
```it`s good```
````

> `` it`s good ``

```
`it\`s good`
```

> `it\`s good` // comments only

Comment: Добавьте вариант с бэкслешем для полноты

Comment: @АндрейNOP А, тоже работает, ща добавлю.

Comment: @АндрейNOP it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: Ну не знаю, в комментарии работает: `\``, автор об этом же спрашивал

Comment: @АндрейNOP `it\`s in comments only`...

Answer (score 3):

В сообщении (`` ` ``):

````
``` ` ```
````

В комментарии:

```
`\``
```

В сообщении или комментарии, если есть другие символы (`` q`w ``):

````
```q`w```
````

Comment: ``` ` ``` - в комментарии не работает :(

Comment: `\`` - а так работает.

Comment: ```q`w``` - вроде работало?